# Using Python decorators to add a method to a method

Tags: python, oop, decorator, python-decorators, theano

I want to be able to call a method according to some standard format:

```
outputs = obj.meth(in_0, in_1, ...)
```

, where outputs is a tuple of arrays, and each input is an array.

However, in most instances, I only return one array, and don't want to be forced to return a tuple of length 1 just for the sake of the standard format. (My actual formatting problem is more complicated but lets stick with this explanation for now.)

I want to be able to define a class like:

```
class _SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._amount_to_add = 1

    @single_return_format
    def add_one(self, x):
        return x+self._amount_to_add
```

And then be able to call it as follows:

```
obj = _SomeClass()
assert obj.add_one(3) == 4
assert obj.add_one.standard_format(3)==(4, )
```

Question is: how do I define the decorator to allow this behaviour?

I tried:

```
def single_return_format(fcn):
    fcn.standard_format = lambda *args: (fcn(*args), )
    return fcn
```

, but it fails on the line with the second assert with:

```
TypeError: add_one() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Because the `add_one` requires "self" as an argument, and the the object has not even been created yet at the time the decorator modifies the function.

So Stack, how can I do this?

---

Notes:

1) I know I could do this with base-classes and inheritance instead, but that becomes a problem when you have more than one method in the class that you want to decorate this way.

2) The actual problem comes from using theano - the standard format is `outputs, updates = fcn(*inputs)`, but most functions don't return any updates, so you want to be able to define those functions in a natural way, but still have the option of calling them according to this standard interface.

Comment: why is theano tagged here?

Comment: See notes at bottom - the problem originated with the fact that, in theano, you are required to represent any state changes in the return value.

Comment: Thanks and sorry, I should have just grepped for the word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dunes gave the correct answer.  I've stripped it down to bare bones so that it solves the problem in the question.  The stripped-down code is here:

```
class single_return_format(object):

    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return SimpleFormMethod(instance, self._func)


class SimpleFormMethod(object):

    def __init__(self, instance, func):
        self._instance = instance
        self._func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._func(self._instance, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def standard_format(self):
        return lambda *args, **kwargs: (self._func(self._instance, *args, **kwargs), )


class _SomeClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._amount_to_add = 1

    @single_return_format
    def add_one(self, x):
        return x+self._amount_to_add


obj = _SomeClass()
assert obj.add_one(3) == 4
assert obj.add_one.standard_format(3) == (4, )
```

Answer (score 2):

That's indeed a problem, because the way the "bound" method is retrieved from the function doesn't consider this way.

I see two ways:

1. You could just wrap the function:

   ```
   def single_return_format(fcn):
       # TODO Do some functools.wraps here...
       return lambda *args, **kwargs: (fcn(*args, **kwargs), )
   ```

   No fooling around with `.standard_format`, but a mere replacement of the function. So the function can define itself as returning one value, but can only be called as returning the tuple.
2. If this is not what you want, you can define a class for decorating methods which overrides `__get__` and does the wrapping in a "live fashion". Of course, it can as well redefine `__call__` so that it is usable for (standalone, non-method) functions as well.

Answer (score 2):

To get exactly what you want you'd have to write a non-data descriptor and a set of wrapper classes for your functions. The reason for this is that the process of getting functions from objects as methods is highly optimised and it's not possible to hijack this mechanism. Instead you have to write your own classes that simulate this mechanism -- which will slow down your code if you are making lots of small method calls.

The very best way I can think to get the desired functionality is not to use any of the methods that you describe, but rather write a wrapper function that you use when needed to call a normal function in the standard format. eg.

```
def vectorise(method, *args, **kwargs):
    return tuple(method(arg, **kwargs) for arg in args)

obj = _SomeClass()

result = vectorise(obj.add_one, 1, 2, 3)
```

Indeed, this is how `numpy` takes functions that operate on one argument and turns them into a function that works on arrays.

```
import numpy

def add_one(x):
    return x + 1

arr = numpy.vectorize(add_one)([1, 2, 3])
```

If you really, really want to use non-data descriptors then following will work. Be warned these method calls are considerably slower. On my computer a normal method call takes 188 nanoseconds versus 1.53 microseconds for a "simple" method call -- a ten-fold difference. And `vectorise` call takes half the time a `standard_form` call does. The vast majority of that time is the lookup of the methods. The actual method calls are quite fast.

```
class simple_form:
    """Allows a simple function to be called in a standard way."""

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func 

    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self.func
        return SimpleFormMethod(self.func, instance)


class MethodBase:
    """Provides support for getting the string representation of methods."""

    def __init__(self, func, instance):
        self.func = func
        self.instance = instance

    def _format(self):
        return "<bound {method_class} {obj_class}.{func} of {obj}>".format(
            method_class=self.__class__.__name__,
            obj_class=self.instance.__class__.__name__,
            func=self.func.__name__,
            obj=self.instance)

    def __str__(self):
        return self._format()

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._format()


class SimpleFormMethod(MethodBase):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.func(self.instance, *args, **kwargs)

    @property
    def standard_form(self):
        return StandardFormMethod(self.func, self.instance)


class StandardFormMethod(MethodBase):

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return tuple(self.func(self.instance, arg, **kwargs) for arg in args)


class Number(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def add_to(self, *values):
        return tuple(val + self.value for val in values)

    @simple_form
    def divide_into(self, value):
        return value / self.value


num = Number(2)
print("normal method access:", num.add_to, sep="\n")
print("simple form method access:", num.divide_into, sep="\n")
print("standard form method access:", num.divide_into.standard_form, sep="\n")
print("access to underlying function:", Number.divide_into, sep="\n")
print("simple example usage:", num.divide_into(3))
print("standard example usage:", num.divide_into.standard_form(*range(3)))
```